# Force Mac window to become full-screen

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I am wondering how to make a window that can’t usually be opened in full-screen (i.e. TextEdit or Dictionary) able to be opened in full-screen by using the full-screen button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Maximizer](http://chpwn.com/apps/maximizer.html). It should work for *all* apps but I haven't checked on it's support. You could also edit app preferences.